# Proof for a limit using epsilon-delta proof and squeeze theorem

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta

Suppose $f$ is a function that satisfies $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 3$. And suppose $f(0) = 0$.

Show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$

Hint: Start by taking $\varepsilon= 1$ in definition of limit for the function $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ and then try to use the squeeze theorem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: .... What is E?

Comment: @BrianO Sorry, it's supposed to be Epsilon. I had trouble formatting.

Comment: Gotcha. "e" would have been less puzzling. Here's an answer below, I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}
=c
$,
where $c$ is some
positive real,
then,
for any $\epsilon > 0$,
for small enough $x$,
$|\frac{f(x)}{x}-c|
< \epsilon
$,
or
$-\epsilon
< \frac{f(x)}{x}-c
< \epsilon
$,
or
$-\epsilon+c
< \frac{f(x)}{x}
< \epsilon+c
$.
Multiplying by $x$,
$x(-\epsilon+c)
< f(x)
< x(\epsilon+c)
$.

Choosing $x$ small enough,
we can make
$f(x)$
as small as we want.
This implies that
$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)
=0
$.

You can make my
"small enough"s more rigorous,
but this is good enough
for me.

Comment: Thank you for the general form like that, it really helps the understanding. Also, how do you do the formatting like that? :p And yes, I get what you're saying with the delta/"small enough"

Comment: @Cody Using LaTeX, markup language for math. Math stackexchange uses the JavaScript library MathJax to render it. You can click "edit" below any answer to see how it's done.

Comment: Technical nit: marty cohen's proof implicitly assumes that $x > 0$. Otherwise, the inequalities flip when you multiply by $x$. It's good enough for me, too, but @Cody: your grader may not be so congenial, so be sure to handle the $x < 0$ case as well. :-)

Comment: @Bungo Already taken care of :)

Comment: @Bungo: Good catch.